# ShowCaseView.Builder cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

I'm using `ShowCaswView` but I get this error in eclipse!
 I imported `ActionBarSherlock` and every thing related to this also I made hard attempt to reach here!
Attached screenshot of error!

What's problem and anyway?

[image]

Comment: have you set the ActionBarSerlock as a Libaray with the Project?

Comment: Yes, I added actionbarsherlock and actionbarsherlock-i18n, But i didn't add actionbarsherlick-fest. beacase had error

Comment: please use this Tutorial : http://adf.ly/3103720/banner/http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-add-actionbarsherlock-library-to.html just to make sure you did it correct.